# Salesforce RestAPI using PHP Guzzle can authenticate but unable to make query

Tags: php, api, salesforce, guzzle

Im using php Guzzle to authenticate to a salesforce sandbox using the script below. The authentication works and I get a token from salesforce, however when i do the next call `$response = $client->request()->get('services/data/v45.0/sobjects/Account/describe`

I get an error `Missing argument 1 for GuzzleHttp\Client::request() on line 59`, which is the request()->get. It seems to fail and im unable to resolve it. If I try it with PostMan api client and workbench and it works without any issue. Thank you for any help in advance.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\{Client, RequestOptions};

$apiCredentials = [
    'client_id' => 'myclientid',
    'client_secret' => 'myclientsecret',
    'security_token' => 'mysecuritytoken',
];
$userCredentials = [
    'username' => 'my@domain.com.sandbox1',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
];

$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://test.salesforce.com/']);
try {
    $response = $client->post('services/oauth2/token', [
        RequestOptions::FORM_PARAMS => [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => $apiCredentials['client_id'],
            'client_secret' => $apiCredentials['client_secret'],
            'username' => $userCredentials['username'],
            'password' => $userCredentials['password'] . $apiCredentials['security_token'],
        ]
    ]);

    $data = json_decode($response->getBody());
    print_r($data);
    echo '<hr>';
} catch (\Exception $exception) {;
    echo 'Unable to connect to Salesforce';
}


$hash = hash_hmac(
    'sha256', 
    $data->id . $data->issued_at, 
    $apiCredentials['client_secret'], 
    true
);
if (base64_encode($hash) !== $data->signature) {
    echo 'Access token is invalid';
}
$accessToken = $data->access_token; // Valid access token


try {
    $response = $client->request()->get('services/data/v45.0/sobjects/Account/describe', [
        RequestOptions::HEADERS => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
            'X-PrettyPrint' => 1,
        ],
    ]);
} catch (\Exception $exception) {
    echo '<hr>Unable to describe Account object<hr>';
}


$accountObject = json_decode($response->getBody());

print_r($accountObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up client construction and request styles. This works:

```php
$client = new Client(...);
$client->get('services/data/...');
```

and this also works:

```php
$client = new Client(...);
$client->request('GET', 'services/data/...');
```

Comment: Thanks but now im getting 'Unable to describe Account object' and I've tired both ways. Remember in postman and even in php curl it works but not guzzle

Comment: That's a different issue, you're no longer getting an `Missing argument 1 for GuzzleHttp\Client::request() on line 59` error from the interpreter. Best to be addressed in a new question.